# AssertionFailedError in ApplicationTestCase.createApplication() in newer Android versions when using MockContext

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-testing

I am writing an Android ApplicationTestCase (TemperatureConverterApplicationTests example found in *Android Application Testing Guide* by Diego T. Milano on page 171). The example was written for Android 2.3 and it doesn't seem to work for Android 4. You don't have to know the book to understand the problem as I have simplified it.

This works fine with **Android 2.3.3** (API 10):

```
setContext(new MockContext());
createApplication();
```

*[To be precise an UnsupportedOperationException is thrown because getPackageName() is not implemented. But this is normal and can be solved by using a subclass of MockContext() that implements getPackageName() and getSharedPreferences(). This is not relevant because the problem still exists even after doing this.]*

The problem is that with **Android 4.1.2** (API 16) it does not work. I get an AssertionFailedError that through some debugging I found out to be due to an ClassCastException being thrown on line 100 of ApplicationTestCase.

```
mApplication = (T) Instrumentation.newApplication(mApplicationClass, getContext());
```

The **ClassCastException** message is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.test.mock.MockContext cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
```

Any suggestions why this happens and how it can be avoided?

EDIT: Related question: [Android ApplicationTestCase using a MockContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205451/android-applicationtestcase-using-a-mockcontext)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. It works fine using a class that extends RenamingDelegatingContext but not a MockContext. I've posted a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205451/android-applicationtestcase-using-a-mockcontext. I'll reply if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I get this behaviour too. I've worked around it by extending ContextWrapper:

```
public class RenamingMockContext extends RenamingDelegatingContext
{
    private static final String PREFIX = "test.";

    public RenamingMockContext(Context context)
    {
        super(new ContextWrapper(context), PREFIX);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageName()
    {
        return PREFIX + super.getPackageName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Instrumentation.newApplication()` method will return an `Application` object. You are trying to cast it to whatever `T` is. If `T` is not a super class or sub class of `Application` you will get a `ClassCastException`. In Java you can only cast an object to something that is a super class or sub class of that object. If it isn't then the exception will be thrown.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

This will throw a `ClassCastException` on the second line because your trying to cast `x` (an `Integer` object) to a `String`. Because a `String` and `Integer` are not sub or super classes of each other.